# expected associated type, found type parameter

Tags: rust, traits, serde, associated-types

I faced an issue wit associated types... I found similar questions on SO, like these ones:

- [Expected type parameter, found opaque type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75510856/expected-type-parameter-found-opaque-type)
- [Matching a generic parameter to an associated type in an impl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345708/matching-a-generic-parameter-to-an-associated-type-in-an-impl)

But while being pretty close to my case, they are not the same...

So I have a trait with associated type:

```rust
trait Generator {
    type Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Self::Item;
}
```

And another trait with generic method which takes first one as a type parameter:

```rust
trait Iterator {
    fn iterate<T>(&self, generator: T) -> T::Item
        where T: Generator;
}
```

So far everything OK.
Now i want to make a struct and implement `Iterator` trait for it.

```rust
struct Baz<R> {      // I want my struct to keep data of the same type as my associated type
    data: Vec<R>,    // So i make my struct generic 
}

impl<R> Iterator for Baz<R>
{
    fn iterate<T>(&self, generator: T) -> T::Item
        where T: Generator<Item = R>     // And specify associated type constraint for generic method
    {
        generator.next()
    }
}
```

And now I'm getting an error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<T as Generator>::Item == R`
  --> src/main.rs:20:28
   |
17 | impl<R> Iterator for Baz<R>
   |      - this type parameter
...
20 |         where T: Generator<Item = R>
   |                            ^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found type parameter `R`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<T as Generator>::Item`
               found type parameter `R`
   = note: you might be missing a type parameter or trait bound
note: the requirement `<T as Generator>::Item == R` appears on the `impl`'s method `iterate` but not on the corresponding trait's method
  --> src/main.rs:9:8
   |
8  | trait Iterator {
   |       -------- in this trait
9  |     fn iterate<T>(&self, generator: T) -> T::Item
   |        ^^^^^^^ this trait's method doesn't have the requirement `<T as Generator>::Item == R`
```

I figured out that to fix it, i have to make my Iterator trait generic and specify constraint in trait definition:

```rust
trait Iterator<R> {
    fn iterate<T>(&self, generator: T) -> T::Item
        where T: Generator<Item = R>;
}
```

And also update impl block:

```rust
impl<R> Iterator<R> for Baz<R>
{
    ...
}
```

But unfortunately this traits are from 3-rd-party lib so I cant update their source code (to be more specific, it's SeqAccess trait from serde library)

So my question is: is there any way to declare associated type constraint in such a case without adding type parameter to trait itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not something you can do. Consider that other functions accepting `impl Iterator` would not be aware of this newly-added constraint and so they could pass a `Generator` whose `Item` type doesn't match your constraint. The signature of the function in `Iterator` imposes no constraint on the type of generated items, so consumers of the trait are free to use any `Generator` at all.

Comment: So is there any way to impl such a 3-rd party trait while storing elements of the same type in struct?

Comment: @zoryamba Nothing stops you from storing whatever you want in your struct. However, you cannot add constraints to a trait method without modifying the trait itself, so you cannot constrain what kind of `Generator` you get passed -- at least not at compile time.

Comment: Yes, i can store anything. But i can't make sure, my generator returns the same type as type i stored in struct. That what i said :) 
Thank you